# What is the maximum recognized fetch size for a ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

As the title states, what is the maximum size recognized by the Java `ResultSet` object?  Specifically the [setFetchSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) function.

```
ResultSet results...;
results.setFetchSize(HUGE_VALUE);
```

More to the point, if there is no "maximum" what is the limiting factor in the size of the fetch?

**COMMENT**

> int is datatype, so I guess it would accept till MAX_INT, remaining
>   things are driver implementation dependent.

Be that as it may that has very little to do with my question, I asked what is recognized not what I can pass to it.  While it may sound like splitting hairs, that is the nature of this question.

**UPDATE**

Since this seems to be getting some "not a real question" close votes.  This is specifically for the Oracle JDBC drivers, `ojdbc14`.  As someone has posted below, I am pulling back result sets in the hundreds of millions, so 30 or 200 is nowhere near the right answer for correct fetch size based on my tests.  At the moment my fetch size is `10,000,000` but there is no way for me to validate that the database is using the size of 10 million.  Further I understand how database hints work, and more often than not you can make the database use the hint you supply, in my experience.

Comment: Remember that the fetch size is just a hint. So the JDBC driver is free to ignore it (or choose a different value). For example if it deems the value you pass in too big.

Comment: @Nambari sure, but does it actually recognize MAX_INT?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well the docs aren't specific enough:   If the fetch size specified is zero, the JDBC driver ignores the value and is free to make its own best guess as to what the fetch size should be. The default value is set by the Statement object that created the result set.   Are you sure that is always the case?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I guess vagueness in documentation could be due to the fact that those details will be specific to driver implementation?

Comment: @Nambari could be, but that is why I posted this question to find a definitive answer.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Make sense, no down votes (or) close votes because question is valid (at least for me). I am interested to find answer too.

Comment: You can pass any positive int you want, and the driver is free to ignore it anyway. I don't see how the documentation is vague. If your specific driver chooses not to ignore it, even for insane values, and you pass MAX_INT, and there are actually 2^31 rows to be fetched, you'll probably get an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @JBNizet the documentation at no point says the driver can ignore it if you supply a value.  The closest thing it says to that is: If the fetch size specified is zero, the JDBC driver ignores the value and is free to make its own best guess as to what the fetch size should be

Comment: It says: "Gives the JDBC driver a hint". A hint is a suggestion, not an order.

Comment: Is there a specific driver you want the answer for?  As mentioned above there is no general answer but there IS an answer for specific drivers.

Comment: @Pace please see the latest update.

Comment: The MySQL driver for example always ignores (or at least: used to ignore) any fetchsize except for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which would cause it to fetch row by row, instead of fetching all (and thus exhausting memory for large resultsets)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `setFetchSize()` method is not doing what you think it is and recommend you read the following two articles closely and do some serious profiling before using a value like 10,000,000.  [This article](http://blog.fatalmind.com/2010/01/29/oracle-jdbc-prefetch-portability/) explains how the JDBC `setFetchSize` is equivalent to Oracle's prefetching capabilities.  It also demonstrates how you can setup some simple profiling to examine the effects of different fetch sizes.  [This article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/oraperf.htm#CHDHDADD) (linked to by the first) explains that there is no maximum value (other than I assume MAX_INT) for the prefetching but warns against using values much larger than a couple hundred.  The second article also mentions the following, further confirming the link between setFetchSize and prefetching:

> Do not mix the JDBC 2.0 fetch size application programming interface
>   (API) and the Oracle row-prefetching API in your application. You can
>   use one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score -1):

This is a hint to the database. Some may not even use this hint. Others may allow a very large value up to the int data type limit. Most however would accept this hint up to the largest reasonable value. Remember that the larger this number is the more memory you will need to use when processing results.

Is this just curiosity or do you plan on setting this to your database max fetch size? If the latter I would strongly urge you against it. Instead, right some tests and performance test based on varying fetch size hints. On some databases 30 may be most optimal and 200 makes the processing even slower. The right number also depends on the size of the row or any blob data, etc.

So, a better question might be -- what is the optimal fetch size for this query on this specific database to which the answer is to try them and measure performance.

Comment: This provides zero information to me.